# Why does HTML Video tag not work on ios devices?

Tags: html, ios, video

I'm trying to make a webpage with a video. It works fine on desktop and android devices but it does not work on ios devices. I have tried to add playsinline, remove autoplay and change the file format (from mp4 to mov) without any success.

my code:

```html
<video loop muted playsinline controls class="video-background" style="
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;">
      <source src="{% static 'somesrc.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Safari needs user interaction to play media. It can even be onClick and then play the video. but the user has to click

Comment: it is not a problem with safari. on ios devices it doesnt work on chrome either

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 6.1, it is no longer possible to auto-play videos on the iPad. According to Apple documentation Autoplay feature is not working on Safari in all ios devices including iPad:

"Apple has made the decision to disable the automatic playing of video on iOS devices, through both script and attribute implementations.

In Safari, on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and auto-play are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it."

Answer (score 0):

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='//some_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

You must use controls = "true" in your opening tag of video and this worked for me . Hope it will show good results